# Using after-change-functions for an ansi-term buffer

Tags: hooks, term, ansi-term

I'm writing some Elisp that compiles code in watch mode using `make-term`. When the code compiles/tests pass, the compilation output is only a couple of lines. When there's an error, it can be much longer. So I would like to resize the window of the term buffer whenever the buffer content changes, to use screen space efficiently.

I tried doing this by adding a function to `after-change-functions` (buffer-locally) that calls `fit-window-to-buffer`, but it never seems to get called. I'm pretty sure the code is right because it works for the `*scratch*` buffer. Is it possible to get this behaviour for term buffers?

Code:

```
  (defun build-watch ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((compile-buffer-name-no-asterisks "compile"))
      (make-term
       compile-buffer-name-no-asterisks
       "compiler"
       nil
       "args")
      (let ((compile-buffer-name (format "*%s*" compile-buffer-name-no-asterisks)))
        (switch-to-buffer-other-window compile-buffer-name)
        (read-only-mode)
        (setq-local
         after-change-functions
         (cons
          (lambda (_start _end _length) (fit-window-to-buffer))
          after-change-functions)))))
```

Comment: I edited your question to say that it's the *window* of the buffer that you want to resize. If that's not what you meant, feel free to fix/undo the edit. Thx.

Comment: Could you post some code that shows just what you're doing? A recipe is always best, especially one that's minimal and starts with `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: @Drew Thanks, added code

Comment: Down-voted due to lack of follow-up, to avoid future Community bumps.

Comment: @phils Not sure what you mean by "lack of follow-up"?

Comment: I mean that I posted an answer at the time which addressed bugs in your code and was under the impression that you hadn't reacted to that at all in the intervening 9 months (in which case it *appeared* to be a dead question, which makes the regular Community bumps to the "active" list an annoyance).  I see now that you actually did take one of my fixes on board; but you've ignored the other, yet neglected comment on any of it.  I'll retract the down-vote if the question is edited (otherwise I can't).

Answer (score 0):

```
-(let ((buffer-name (format "*%s*" compile-buffer-name-no-asterisks)))
+(let ((compile-buffer-name (format "*%s*" compile-buffer-name-no-asterisks)))
```

Also, you should use `add-hook` with its `LOCAL` argument to add buffer-local hook functions (even with abnormal hooks like `after-change-functions`).  Your current approach will cause multiple kinds of duplication.